# radius of the curvature at the origin

Tags: curvature

**Find the radius of curvature at the origin of the curve**
$$y^2-2xy-3x^2-4x^3-x^2y^2 = 0$$

In this math, 
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {y+3x+6x^2+xy^2}{y-x-yx^2}$$ and $$\frac {dx}{dy} = \frac {y-x-yx^2}{y+3x+6x^2+xy^2}$$
**At $(0, 0)$  both** $$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {0}{0} $$ and $$ \frac {dx}{dy} = \frac {0}{0}$$
So, I am not able to apply the equations $$\rho=\dfrac{{(1+y_1^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}{y_2}$$ and
$$\rho=\dfrac{{(1+x_1^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x_2}$$

**Then, how do I find the tangent and radius of the curvature?**

Comment: I would suggest that you show how you got your values for the derivatives.  I don't get infinities at all.  Also, sorry, but something is clearly wrong here because $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$ cannot be infinite at the same time.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I have edited the question and the solving process is still unknown to me.

Comment: OK.  That's better.  Zero divided by zero is absolutely not always infinity!  You are going to have to find the *limit* of the derivative as $x$ approaches zero.  Others might have a better way, but I would suggest starting with your original function and solving for $y$ in terms of $x$.  It will be a bit of a mess, but it can be done since it will just boil down to a quadratic equation for $y$.  Then see what happens to the derivative of that function as $x$ approaches zero.